# Não esta identificando para carregar dados no mapa so identifica apenas 1 ip

Tags: php

```
<?php
    for($a=0;$a<$total_ouvintes;$a++){
        $locations = $ipLite->getCity("$contip[$a]");
        echo "var myLatlng$a = new google.maps.LatLng( $locations[latitude], $locations[longitude]);\n";
    }
?> 
  var locationArray = [<?php for($b=0;$b<$total_ouvintes;$b++){ echo "myLatlng$b,";}?>];
  var locationArrayName = [<?php for($c=0;$c<$total_ouvintes;$c++){echo '"'."Ouvinte: $contip[$c]".'",';}?>];

  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(5,-20),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa_ips"), myOptions);

 for(var cont = 0; cont < locationArray.length; cont++) {


 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locationArray[cont],
    title: locationArrayName[cont]
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  }
}
```